# How can I draw a "rhombus'ish" shape in a grid around a point

Tags: javascript, 2d, processing, p5.js

I'm struggling with this problem for some days and I can't get the logic behind it.
I have a 10x10 grid with a square in the x = 5 y = 5 position, like in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Wlj.png)...

[image]

I know how I can draw around that square with a range = 2, like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbLNr.png).

[image]

Code sample:

```
const pos = {x: 5, y: 5};
const range = 2; // Range can vary
const square = [...] // Square is an array of positions like [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 0} ...]

for ... {
    if (pos.x - range <= square[i].x && pos.x + range >= square[i].x &&
        pos.y - range <= square[i].y && pos.y + range >= square[i].y) {
        fill("red");
        square(square[i].x * 10,
           square[i].y * 10,
           10);
    }
}
```

The desired effect that I'm trying to make [is this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1OBt.png), but I have no clue of how I can achieve it...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance of the filed to `pos` has to be less than `range`. Create to nested loops and run through each filed. Compute the distance in x and y direction (`dx`, dy). Use [`abs`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/abs) to compute the absolute distance. Evaluate if the sum of `dx` and `dy` is less or equal `range`:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; ++ j) {
        let dx = abs(pos.x - i);
        let dy = abs(pos.y - j);

        if (dx + dy <= range) {
            fill(dx + dy == 0 ? "blue" : "red");
            rect(gx*i, gy*j, gx, gy);
        }
    }
}
```

See the example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

const pos = {x: 5, y: 5};
const range = 2;

function draw() {
   
    let gx = width / 10;
    let gy = height / 10;

    background((255, 255, 255));

    noStroke();
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 10; ++ j) {
            let dx = abs(pos.x - i);
            let dy = abs(pos.y - j);
            
            if (dx + dy <= range) {
                fill(dx + dy == 0 ? "blue" : "red");
                rect(gx*i, gy*j, gx, gy);
            }
        }
    }

    noFill();
    stroke("black");
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; ++ i) {
        line(gx*i, 0, gx*i, height);
        line(0, gy*i, width, gy*i);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a super easy way to solve the problem. It involves using an array arranged in a 10 X 10 grid of numbers. 0s on the grid represent all the positions where we want to draw white squares. 1s on the grid represent all the positions where we want to draw red squares. 2s on the grid represent all the positions where we want to draw blue squares. There is no need to know the relative values of x and y points or the range value. All you need to do is to change the position of 0s,1s and 2s on the grid and the function will draw the pattern you want.

The code is as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 
/* 
 * The grid is a 10 by 10 array of numbers. 
 * The 0s represent all the spots where you want a white square. 
 * The 1s represent all the spots where you want a red square.
 * The 2s represent all the spots where you want a blue square(the middle spot in this case)
 */  
var grid = 
[ 
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
];
function drawSquares(grid)
{ 
    grid.forEach((row,rowIndex) => 
    {
        row.forEach((square,squareIndex) => 
        {   
            switch(square)
            {
                case 1: //if the grid value is a 1, draw a red square
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(50*squareIndex,50* rowIndex, 50, 50);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.lineWidth   = "1";
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";  
                    ctx.stroke();
                    break;
                case 2: //if the grid value is a 2, draw a blue square
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(50*squareIndex,50* rowIndex, 50, 50);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.lineWidth   = "1";
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                    ctx.stroke();
                    break;
                case 0: //if the grid value is a 0, draw a white square
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(50*squareIndex,50* rowIndex, 50, 50);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.lineWidth   = "1";
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                    ctx.stroke();
                    break; 
            } 
        }); 
    });   
}
drawSquares(grid);
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

The output of the above code is as follows: 
[image]

Usage example:

```
//Example 1: 
//To achieve your second result,the grid is changed as follows:
var grid = 
[ 
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
];
drawSquares(grid);//after the function call, the result is as shown below
```

[image]

```
//Example 2: 
//To achieve your first result,the grid is changed as follows:
var grid = 
[ 
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
];
drawSquares(grid);//after the function call, the result is as shown below
```

[image]